# How to display a blank form for a short time (C#)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a little project that involves a lot of similar screens, I want to display a blank form for a second so users would notice there was a change. The controls for each screen are in a groupbox, I tried this:

```
private void Wait(int _mode, int _interval)
{
    GroupBox gb = (_mode == 0)? grp1 : grp2;
    gb.Visible = false;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(_interval);
    gb.Visible = true;
}
```

This causes an issue of not displaying a brush element when the group is visible again.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY  Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), There are other ways to draw attention to changing in detail, showing a white screen to me would make me think that your application is buggy/laggy

Comment: Show a small loading window instead

Comment: What would you do to indicate something changed? The client wants to make sure people notice the situation is different than it was before and insists on displaying a blank screen because "That will make sure they notice".

Basically, I have two pictureboxes with a brush drawing a border around one of them. When the controls are visible again, the borders are not drawn.

Comment: There must be some other issue because you example works for me without any problems. What other controls do you have in your group box?

Comment: What is a _brush element_?

Comment: Why not "flashing" (i.e. changing background color excessively) of the items that were changed/updated? It would look more professional and "fancy".